# LDAP authentication isnt happening over django rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am authenticating users who login against through django REST framework against NIS using pythonPAM . But when I make the changes to settings.py as mentioned below, user credentials isnt being verified against LDAP.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
)
```

This along with ldap credentials for binding is used. 
Note: I can connect to LDAP server and get all teh details. Its only a problem with django restframework.

I also tried

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =  [ 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',]
```

and it did not work.

Currently in my urls.py, I call url(/login,) endpoint and authenticate against NIS server. How do I change it to LDAP?

I am new to django and need help on this.

Comment: So what happens when you try and authenticate using the `LDAPBackend`? Do you get an error, or just an authentication failure and no error?

Comment: So, I was getting credentials error, and I couldn't understand if it was LDAP rejecting it or the settings.py was not taking in the changes. i put 'all-auth ' in installed apps setting in settings.py and did enchanced logging as mentioned in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048962/django-auth-ldap-failed-authentication . Now it is authenticating. Django 1.11 needs more configuration with LDAP i guess.

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
) worked after I corrected the ldap settiings